# Loop - LASSO Coefficient extraction from simulation data

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, coefficients, lasso-regression

I am attempting to find which coefficients were properly and unproerly shrunk to 0 from a LASSO experiment on simulated data. I can get it to work over a single iteration, but I do not know how to properly loop it so that I can extract the relevant information for 100 iterations.
Here's my current code

```
library(MASS)
library(glmnet)
N=100
n=200
p=200


set.seed(123)
f.non<-data.frame(NULL)
f.disc<-data.frame(NULL)

  X= mvrnorm(200, rep(0,p), diag(1,p,p))
  Y=rowSums(X[,1:10])+3.5*rnorm(n)
  lasso.model<-cv.glmnet(X,Y,alpha=1,intercept=FALSE)
  lasso.coef<-coef(lasso.model,s=lasso.model$lambda.1se)
  f.non<- sum(lasso.coef[2:11,] == 0)
  f.disc <- sum(lasso.coef[12:201,] != 0)

}
```

The upper chunk was my try at looping through by setting up an empty data frame, then in the loop catching the results but I couldn't get the loop to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly (and I'm not sure that I do) you're trying to extract the values (and names?) of  your `lasso.coef` object, depending on whether or not they're equal to zero.

You can do that 100 times in a `for` loop like this (if you want to collect the names of the variables):

```
f.non <- c(NULL)
f.disc <- c(NULL)
N=100
for (i in 1:N) {
  n=200
  p=200
  X = mvrnorm(200, rep(0, p), diag(1, p, p))
  Y = rowSums(X[, 1:10]) + 3.5 * rnorm(n)
  lasso.model <- cv.glmnet(X, Y, alpha = 1, intercept = FALSE)
  lasso.coef <- coef(lasso.model, s = lasso.model$lambda.1se)
  # lasso_coefs <- lasso.coef[2:201]
  # setNames(lasso_coefs, paste("V", as.character(seq(2, 201, 1)), sep = ""))
  lasso_coefs_df <- data.frame(coef = lasso.coef[2:201], name = paste("V", as.character(seq(2,201,1)), sep = ""))

  # f.non[[i]] <- as.list(lasso_coefs[lasso_coefs == 0])
  # f.disc[[i]] <- as.list(lasso_coefs[lasso_coefs != 0])
  f.non[[i]] <- lasso_coefs_df[lasso_coefs_df$coef == 0, ]
  f.disc[[i]] <- lasso_coefs_df[lasso_coefs_df$coef != 0, ]
}
```

Otherwise, and more similar to your attempt, if you just want the sums of each range of varialbes (2-11, 12-201):

```
f.non <- c(NULL)
f.disc <- c(NULL)
N=100
for (i in 1:N) {
  n=200
  p=200
  X = mvrnorm(200, rep(0, p), diag(1, p, p))
  Y = rowSums(X[, 1:10]) + 3.5 * rnorm(n)
  lasso.model <- cv.glmnet(X, Y, alpha = 1, intercept = FALSE)
  lasso.coef <- coef(lasso.model, s = lasso.model$lambda.1se)
  f.non[[i]] <- sum(lasso.coef[2:11,] == 0)
  f.disc[[i]] <- sum(lasso.coef[12:201,] != 0)
}
```

Comment: I need to loop through this process 100 times. I can do it for 1 dataset, but I have to create 100 datasets based on this idea and do the same each time. The part that is stumping me is extracting this information for each iteration of a new dataset. The first 10 X values should not be shrunk to 0 as they form the Y value + 3.5*rnorm, the next group [12;201] do not have anything to do with the Y prediction in theory however Lasso will not always shrink every column to 0, which is the information I am trying to extract over r100 iterations of this process to examine

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying.  A further question - which part runs 100 times - the ```cv.glmnet``` call?

Comment: I should be creating 100 datasets, ie 100 sets of an X matrix which is 200x200, and 100 sets of a 200x1 Y matrix

Comment: @j4k I've modified the answer to loop over 100 iterations and extract variables that equal and don't equal 0.  Is that what you're looking for?